# How in livewire after clicking on gotoPage method to call JS function?

Tags: javascript, laravel-livewire

In laravel 7 with livewire 1.3 I have a listing with pagination and lazy images
applied to any item image by calling JS function lazyImagesInit(lazyload 2.0.0-rc.2 is used)
when page is loaded. But when I click on pagination link I lose lazy images effect for any
new opened items images .
Looking into the code of cach file I see that gotoPage method is used :

```
<?php if(is_array($element)): ?>
    <?php $__currentLoopData = $element; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $page => $url): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
        <?php if($page == $paginator->currentPage()): ?>
            <li class="page-item active d-none d-md-block" aria-current="page"><span class="page-link"><?php echo e($page); ?></span></li>
        <?php else: ?>
            <li class="page-item d-none d-md-block"><button type="button" class="page-link" wire:click="gotoPage(<?php echo e($page); ?>)"><?php echo e($page); ?></button></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; $__env->popLoop(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If there is a way after calling of gotoPage to call my lazyImagesInit function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override the `goToPage()` method on your component -

```
public function gotoPage($page)
{
    $this->page = $page;

    $this->emit('goToPage');
}
```

Now listen for the `goToPage` event in JavaScript and call the `lazyImagesInit` function -

```
<script>
window.livewire.on('goToPage', () => {
    lazyImagesInit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: tHANKS!. It helped! Are there some other methods of component I can override in such way? Could you please provide a link ?

Comment: Great to hear! Mark my answer as correct if it helped you :)

If you take a look at the Component class and other traits that you use in your component then you can explore the all the methods that you are able to override - https://github.com/livewire/livewire